# Secure /oauth/authorize endpoint same like /oauth/token

Tags: spring-security, oauth, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

In OAuth 2 TokenEndpoint whenever we are calling /oauth/token endpoint, BaseAuthenticationFilter is being called and Client is authenticated. But same BaseAuthenticationFilter is not registered for /oauth/authorize endpoint.

Because of which the Principal Object is not getting populated and is null for /oauth/authorize mapping.

How can we register the same for /oauth/authorize endpoint ?

Comment: could you please elaborate what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: @SergeyPonomarev